# Appending vector creating two separate lists in R

Tags: r, string, list, append

I am new in R and I am quite confused about the data structure. I am dealing with two vectors, each vector containing strings of character as below:

vector1:
[image]

vector2:
[image]

And in order to append these vectors, I used the append function as follows:
`text_append <- append(vector1, vector2)`

But, once I append it, it creates two separate lists, whereas I wanted it to become just 1 list
[image]

How can I make sure that I make 1 whole list of strings? I am compiling the strings, and making them as separate list wont help. I dont know what else to do.

Thanks for the help

I tried to use the append function

`text_append <- append(vector1, vector2)`

I expected it to retrieve me a single list of strings, but instead it gives me two separate lists.

Comment: If `class(v1)` says `list` you have to unlist them before concatenation. E.g. `c(unlist(v1), unlist(v2))`

Comment: or `unlist(c(v1,v2))`  ... in any case, the problem is that your vector2 is a list (with one element), not a plain vector

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lebatsnok I have somehow managed to solve my problem but I believe it was because the class(v1)and(v2) were lists.

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating two vectors of strings just use `c(vector1, vector2)`. If you want to make a list with the elements being made of the strings use `as.list(c(vector1, vector2))`

Comment: I tried the c() method but it unfortunately still creates 2 separate lists.